# IndexError: tuple index out of range with skimage.morphology.binary_closing

Tags: python, tuples, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

I am using skimage and applying a morphological binary closing to an array by setting the footprint to a disk equal to 5. When I run the code with the default values and without the `footprint = disk(5)` the code works but when I add the footprint parameter it throws an error:

```
from skimage.morphology import disk
import skimage.feature
import skimage.morphology
import rasterio as rio
import rasterio.plot

footprint = disk(5)
    
flood_closing = skimage.morphology.binary_closing(flood_uint8_test, footprint)
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-10bd8239dd40> in <module>
----> 1 flood_closing = skimage.morphology.binary_closing(flood_uint8_test, footprint)

~/anaconda3/envs/eobox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/morphology/misc.py in func_out(image, selem, *args, **kwargs)
     37         if selem is None:
     38             selem = _default_selem(image.ndim)
---> 39         return func(image, selem=selem, *args, **kwargs)
     40 
     41     return func_out

~/anaconda3/envs/eobox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/morphology/binary.py in binary_closing(image, selem, out)
    142 
    143     """
--> 144     dilated = binary_dilation(image, selem)
    145     out = binary_erosion(dilated, selem, out=out)
    146     return out

~/anaconda3/envs/eobox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/morphology/misc.py in func_out(image, selem, *args, **kwargs)
     37         if selem is None:
     38             selem = _default_selem(image.ndim)
---> 39         return func(image, selem=selem, *args, **kwargs)
     40 
     41     return func_out

~/anaconda3/envs/eobox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/morphology/binary.py in binary_dilation(image, selem, out)
     75     if out is None:
     76         out = np.empty(image.shape, dtype=np.bool)
---> 77     ndi.binary_dilation(image, structure=selem, output=out)
     78     return out
     79 

~/anaconda3/envs/eobox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/ndimage/morphology.py in binary_dilation(input, structure, iterations, mask, output, border_value, origin, brute_force)
    513     for ii in range(len(origin)):
    514         origin[ii] = -origin[ii]
--> 515         if not structure.shape[ii] & 1:
    516             origin[ii] -= 1
    517 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I'd guess, `flood_uint8_test` is a multi-channel / color image, and not a single-channel / grayscale image. `disk` is a specific 2-dimensional structuring element, which can only be used with single-channel / grayscale images - which also explains why the code works without specifying any structuring element.